# Fixed position menu when scrolling until it hits the bottom of a relative container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to simulate what Yelp does with their [Mo Map](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco,%20CA&ns=1).

I know how to get an flip an element to fixed position once it reaches a certain screen scroll position, but how do you turn off fixed position once it hits the bottom of a relative container?

The [css sticky position](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit) solves this, but since its fairly new, it doesnt have great coverage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try doing something like this: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/yLRVZ/).

Here's a commented version of the JavaScript: (note: this uses jQuery, but it isn't necessary. If you need a plain JavaScript version I'd be glad to provide some hints)

```
var oritop = -100;
$(window).scroll(function() { //on scroll,
    var scrollt = window.scrollY; //get the amount of scrolling
    var elm = $(".box"); //get the box we want to make sticky
    if(oritop < 0) {
        oritop= elm.offset().top; //cache the original top offset
    }
    if(scrollt >= oritop) { //if you scrolled past it,
        elm.css({"position": "fixed", "top": 0, "left": 0}); //make it sticky
    }
    else { //otherwise
        elm.css("position", "static"); //reset it to default positioning
    }
});
```

Comment: This is close, the different about what i'm trying to achieve is the blue box shouldn't go over outside the grey outter-content box. It should stay contained within that box. http://jsfiddle.net/yLRVZ/1/

Comment: @Dan An additional `if` is sufficient: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/yLRVZ/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by marking the selected item.

Function that places the menu with absolute position when scrolling and marks the selected item:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop());
   // x = jQuery("html").scrollTop();  

    x = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); // corrigindo bug do chome

    /* Item marcado de acordo com a rolagem */
    switch (true) {
    case (x >= 600 && x < 2500): // ajuste aqui a area    
        jQuery('.coluna-222-right a').removeClass('ativo');
        jQuery('.coluna-222-right a.programacao').addClass('ativo');           
        break;
    case (x >= 2500 && x < 5000):
        jQuery('.coluna-222-right a').removeClass('ativo');  // ajuste aqui a area 
        jQuery('.coluna-222-right a.palestrantes').addClass('ativo');                  
        break;
    case (x >= 5000 && x < 5765):
        jQuery('.coluna-222-right a').removeClass('ativo');  // ajuste aqui a area 
        jQuery('.coluna-222-right a.local').addClass('ativo');
        break;
    } 


    if (x>40) {     
    jQuery(".coluna-222-right ul").css("position","absolute");
    jQuery(".coluna-222-right ul").css("top",x+20);   // ajuste aqui a posição do menu, pode usar - ao invés de +
    }

    else {          
    jQuery(".coluna-222-right ul").css("position","static");
    jQuery(".coluna-222-right ul").css("top","0");  
        }   

});
```

Check the item clicked:

```
jQuery("a").click(function () {
    jQuery("a").removeClass("ativo");
    jQuery(this).addClass("ativo");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67fwh/

Comment: Friend, I translated, but keep in mind that we of Brazil use the American stackoverflow a lot.

Everyone can make a force to understand, right?

Tnks

Comment: Please note that this site is **English only**. I removed the Portuguese texts as they are "noise" (see [faq] and [tour]). Having your variables in English is optional but may increase your chances of helping the rest of the world and receive upvotes for that.

Comment: Ok, fine tanks.